# Yum not Detecting phpMyAdmin Updates

Tags: centos, yum

Yum seems to not detect any updates for phpMyAdmin. Upon installing, it installed a slightly outdated version, but no updates have been noticed since. Even though phpMyAdmin says "new update available,"

```
 yum update
```

doesn't include any update for PMA. Upon doing

```
 yum update phpMyAdmin
```

it says

> Setting up Update Process
>
> No Packages marked for Update

I have not found any documentation on this via the CentOS *or* phpMyAdmin sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpMyAdmin releases won't correspond 1-to-1 to yum package releases. You have to wait for the CentOS repositories to release a new version of the package, or you can manually upgrade phpMyAdmin yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How will it know I'm up-to-date if I update manually? Will it screw up future updates?

Comment: Well don't overwrite the 'official' files, i mean /usr/share/phpmyadmin and /etc/phpmyadmin . Maybe the best to remove phpMyAdmin rpm and install manually from phpMyAdmin site. That way you could avoid further confusion.

Comment: @rtainc - Manual update in this case means, as a better practice, rolling out your own rpm.

Answer (score 2):

I found the latest version of phpMyAdmin in the remi repo:

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
yum --enablerepo=remi update phpmyadmin
```

for CentOS6. More info and instructions for different distributions in this link:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-phpmyadmin-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: that 'udpate' should be 'update' - can't edit just 1 char here...